# Connected Lie group 1-dimensional isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or to $S^1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ a connected Lie group of dimension 1. Show that
\begin{align}
G \cong \mathbb{R} \, \, \, \text{or} \, \, \, G \cong S^1
\end{align}

I tried to read and understand the 
topic
[Connected, one-dimensional Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142295/connected-one-dimensional-lie-groups) , but I have some problem to compute the kernel of the exponential map to see that $\ker(\exp) = \{ 0 \}$ or $\ker(\exp)= r\mathbb{Z}$ for some $r>0$.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Closed subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ are of the form $\mathbb{R}$ or $r\mathbb{Z}$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ only. You don't need to compute the exponential map at all. See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/subgroup-of-mathbbr-either-dense-or-has-a-least-positive-element

Comment: And this for more details: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.7067.pdf